# pow() in C is not working properly

Tags: c, pow

I dont know if i have missunderstood the concept of pow, but i've tried a lot of things, however, would appreciate some help here why pow isnt working.
Im trying to calculate the BMI which is BMI = weight/(lenght^2)  I know i could just do (lenght*2) but i want to learn the pow function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()


{
    float langd1;
    float langd2;
    float langd3;
    float langd4;
    float vikt1;
    float vikt2;
    float vikt3;
    float vikt4;

    {

        printf("Whats your weight?");
        scanf_s("%f", &vikt1);
        printf("Whats your weight?");
        scanf_s("%f", &vikt2);
        printf("Whats your weight?");
        scanf_s("%f", &vikt3);
        printf("Whats your weight?");
        scanf_s("%f", &vikt4);

        printf("Whats your lenght?");
        scanf_s("%f", &langd1);
        printf("Whats your lenght?");
        scanf_s("%f", &langd2);
        printf("Whats your lenght?");
        scanf_s("%f", &langd3);
        printf("Whats your lenght?");
        scanf_s("%f", &langd4);

        printf("User 1, your BMI is %f", vikt1 / pow(langd1));

        system("pause");


    }
    getchar();
    return(0);


}
```

Comment: `pow()` takes two arguments, you're giving it one. Shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `pow(x,y)` most definitely is not the same as `2*x` ...

Comment: @Jongware Unless `x == 2`, but that's an edge case.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `pow(langd1,2)`.

`pow()` takes two arguments. The first is the base, the second one is the exponent. It returns `(base ^ exponent)`.

If you don't give it the second parameter, it invokes undefined behavior. **edit:** Actually it just won't compile. I had that confused with variadic arguments.

For more details, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm

Comment: How could it even compile without a matching signature?

Comment: I would never use pow(x,2).  What's wrong with x*x ?